# GPT4-v images labeling: 'Classifications' object is not iterable

Tags: computer-vision, openai-api, yolo, gpt-4

Following this article [Image Classification](https://blog.roboflow.com/gpt-4-image-classification/) I try to label images with specific categories using GPT4-Visual API, so that I can use these classifications to train a YOLOv8 model.
At the end I get *TypeError: 'Classifications' object is not iterable*
Here is my code:

```
from autodistill_gpt_4v import GPT4V
from autodistill.detection import CaptionOntology
import os


api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

base_model = GPT4V(
    api_key=api_key,
    ontology=CaptionOntology(
        {
            "scratch": "scratch"
        }
    )
)
base_model.label("./images/", extension=".jpg")
```

Here is error trace:

```
base_model.label("./images/", extension=".jpg")
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\autodistill\detection\detection_base_model.py", line 64, in label
    dataset.as_yolo(
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\supervision\dataset\core.py", line 363, in as_yolo
    save_yolo_annotations(
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\supervision\dataset\formats\yolo.py", line 239, in save_yolo_annotations
    lines = detections_to_yolo_annotations(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\supervision\dataset\formats\yolo.py", line 198, in detections_to_yolo_annotations
    for xyxy, mask, _, class_id, _ in detections:
TypeError: 'Classifications' object is not iterable
```

I tried to print the detections object passed to the

```
detections_to_yolo_annotations(detections: Detections, 
    image_shape: Tuple[int, int, int],
    min_image_area_percentage: float = 0.0,
    max_image_area_percentage: float = 1.0,
    approximation_percentage: float = 0.75,)
```

and got
`Classifications(class_id=array([0]), confidence=array([1]))`